# How to forward a mutable lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, template-meta-programming

Here's a watered down example of the code I'm try to compile:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <class F>
auto foo(F&& fun)
{
    return [callback = std::forward<F>(fun)](auto&&... args) {
        std::invoke(callback, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}

int main()
{
    std::string cur("running"), target("ok");
    
    foo([s1 = cur, s2 = target](std::string const& arg) /*mutable*/ {
        if (s1 == arg)
        {
            std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
        }
    })("not ok");
    
    return 0;
}
```

put simply I have a function `foo` that accepts callables, and is supposed to build a new callable from them. For the sake of the example, above I'm just invoking the `fun` argument but in the real case there are some decorations done to the callable and the result is placed into a data structure that invokes such "actions" under some conditions.

This example [compiles and works just fine](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/905fbf65028781da). The problem **manifests when trying to pass mutable lambdas to `foo`**. When I uncomment the `mutable` keyword above, I get this compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'foo<main()::<lambda(const string&)> >(main()::<lambda(const string&)>&&)::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)> [with auto:1 = {const char (&)[7]}]':

main.cpp:21:7:   required from here

main.cpp:8:20: error: no matching function for call to 'invoke(const main()::<lambda(const string&)>&, const char [7])'

    8 |         std::invoke(callback, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

In file included from main.cpp:2:

/usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/functional:94:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::invoke_result_t<_Callable, _Args ...> std::invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)'

   94 |     invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)

      |     ^~~~~~

/usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/functional:94:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/move.h:57,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/nested_exception.h:40,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/exception:148,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/ios:39,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/ostream:38,

                 from /usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/iostream:39,

                 from main.cpp:1:

/usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits: In substitution of 'template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> using invoke_result_t = typename std::invoke_result::type [with _Fn = const main()::<lambda(const string&)>&; _Args = {const char (&)[7]}]':

/usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/functional:94:5:   required by substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::invoke_result_t<_Callable, _Args ...> std::invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = const main()::<lambda(const string&)>&; _Args = {const char (&)[7]}]'

main.cpp:8:20:   required from 'foo<main()::<lambda(const string&)> >(main()::<lambda(const string&)>&&)::<lambda(auto:1&& ...)> [with auto:1 = {const char (&)[7]}]'

main.cpp:21:7:   required from here

/usr/local/include/c++/11.2.0/type_traits:2933:11: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::invoke_result<const main()::<lambda(const string&)>&, const char (&)[7]>'

 2933 |     using invoke_result_t = typename invoke_result<_Fn, _Args...>::type;

      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any idea why is that? Can my `foo` accept mutable lambdas as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `mutable` to the lambda inside the `foo`:

```
template <class F>
auto foo(F&& fun)
{
    return [callback = std::forward<F>(fun)](auto&&... args) mutable {
                                                             //^^^
        std::invoke(callback, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Comment: But why? Isn't that new lambda unrelated to the `fun`? I mean I'm not trying to modify the captured callable, just invoke it

Comment: The `operator()` of the lambda inside `foo` is const-qualified, so the `callback` is also const-qualified, which means it cannot call the non-const qualified `operator()`.

Comment: ok and purely by being `mutable`, the original lambda has deleted its `const operator()()` so `foo` cannot call it -- or rather that operator does not exist to begin with and `foo` has nothing to call . Thanks makes sense

Comment: Can that `foo` routine add `mutable` based on whether the `fun` parameter is `mutable`?  A kind of manual "transitive mutable".

Comment: @Eljay I'm afraid not, but the C++20 [`bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) [can](https://godbolt.org/z/8fM4fKr33) do this since it has four differently qualified `operator()`.